# detect scroll in horizontally uitableviewCell

Tags: xcode, uitableview, scroll

I have UiTableView containing some data, and I want to scroll the UiTableViewCells horizontally to the left or right to show some UiButtons that act some action relatif to the content of the cell.

How Can I do this?

I'm thinking in creating custom cell, and putting a scrollView in it, May this did the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tutorial for this at http://idevrecipes.com/2011/04/14/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-side-swiping-on-a-table/ with sample code. He is using a [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to trigger an animation that pushes the cell off the screen.

[image: result]

Comment: The navigation controller is not relevant, probably came with the new project template. It's a complex code and there is no way around it. I suggest you make a view based project, create a custom table view controller, custom cell, and start adding code bit by bit from the idevrecipes project. You'll have time to read each part and see what it does. OR add everything to your project, change the buttons at viewDidLoad and change the button reaction in touchUpInsideAction. You don't need the delegate and the mainwindow.xib.

Comment: thanks a lot Jano, I did exactly as you suggested in the first way, a new project and adding slowly some codes, and it works finally like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a swipe gesture recognizer attached to your cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `UIScrollView` to the `contentView` of a `UITableViewCell`. If you want to scroll the content using buttons, simply overlay the `UIScrollView` with buttons and make them call the various scrolling methods of UIScrollView.

Nested `UIScrollView` (`UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`) are quite clever about detecting touch conflicts and resolving the users intended gesture.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGScrollableTableViewCell might be what you're looking for. It implements this using a UIScrollView inside the cell (just like the iOS 7 mail app).

(Yes the answer is a bit late, but it's never too late! :P)